# Printing in java using Dot matrix printer doesn't print the same as that of Inkjet printer

Tags: java, printing

I have developed a billing software for a retail shop and i tried billing receipts using an inkjet printer. When i tried the same using a dot matrix printer, the print out was not good. The letters are overlapped. And it is difficult to read. Do i need to change anything in my printing program? I am using printerJob class for printing. I have tried changing fonts and font size within the printing code, nothing helped me.

Comment: Show us the code you are using.

Comment: Sometimes printers use the own fonts. This can cause problems if they have different geometrics.